# How to get pointer name

Tags: c++

Actually I am hooking memory management functions but one problem that confronts me is that I am unable to get the pointer name for which memory is being allocated in my hooked function.
I mean...
suppose Myfunction() allocates memory to a pointer Myptr through new operator as geven below.

```
Myfunction()
{
    int * Myptr = new int;
}
```

Now here I want that when My hooked function "Mynew" is called for memory allocation, it should know the name of the pointer Myptr for whom memory is being allocated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

You could do something similar with a macro, so that it passes the variable name to a function:

```
#define NEWPTR(var, type) type * var = allocate_memory(type, #var)
```

Answer (score 1):

The pointer name is only known at compile time, not at runtime. Also, the allocation `new int` is an expression separate from its assignment to the `Myptr` variable. You're redefining allocators, not the assignment operator for pointers (I hope!)...

As @Sjoerd suggests, you could get something like this for your own code by introducing a macro calling your own allocation function. I'm not sure if this is what you really need.